# Routing and admin scope not working well

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this code on my `routes.php` file:

```
Router::scope('/admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'dashboard']);
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->connect('/logout', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout']);
});

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

When I visit `http://localhost/admin` with an unauthenticated user, I want to be redirect to `http://localhost/admin/login`. At this moment I'm being redirected to `http://localhost/login`

If I change the code, adding the line `$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);` at the admin scope, the redirection for the login will work well, but all my links will be generated with `admin` prefix like:

```
<?= $this->Html->link($category->name, ['controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $category->id]) ?>
```

Will generate:

> http://localhost/admin/categories/view/13

instead of:

> http://localhost/categories/view/13

How can I solve this?

Comment: @SamHecquet I think if I put outside I will not be able to access $routes variable (object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a routes issue.  Can't you just specify `unauthorizedRedirect` in your Auth array? Like this:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    //...
    'unauthorizedRedirect' => [
        'controller'=>'Users',
        'action'=>'login',
        'prefix'=>'admin'
    ]
]);
```

More info [here in the CakePHP book](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#redirecting-users-after-login).

> **unauthorizedRedirect**: Controls handling of unauthorized access. By
>   default unauthorized user is redirected to the referrer URL or
>   loginAction or ‘/’.

Comment: This works. But my question is: Why with unauthorizedRedirect works, but with loginAction don't?

Comment: `loginAction` would work too if you specify the `admin` prefix. This just seemed more specific to what you were going for. But you didn't include either in your provided code, so it's hard to say if/why your particular attempt isn't working.

Comment: I tried to use the `admin` prefix on the `loginAction`... the same way as the `unauthorizedRedirect `  and did not work